# How to update firebase realtime database based on a value in array of objects in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to flutter as well as firebase and have structured my data as follows:

```
  {
      "a": {
        "b" : [ {
          "property1" : value1,
          "property2" : value2
           }, {
          "property1" : value3,
          "property2" : value4
          }]
       }
    }
```

Firebase database has numbered my array objects as 0,1

As you can see b contains array of objects, how do I create a query if I want to update a value in object which contains property2 value as value2 ? Do I have to modify my database structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with a single update. You're going to have to:

1. Query the children of a/b to find the child that contains value2. The name will be a string with the index of the child you found.
2. With the name of that found child, perform an update of `a/b/{child}`.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, so there is no way to perform this in a single query other than changing the structure of database?

Comment: No. That's the very first thing I said in the answer.