# Can I add multiple details in firebase document field?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to add multiple details in the field of a firebase document.

suppose, I have a field (let's suppose 'mobile number') in a document.

mobile number -
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx

I want to add multiple items in mobile number , how can i do that in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding the phone numbers as an array of that field.

using Firestore:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
users.doc().add({'mobile_number': ['+1234567890','+0987654321']});
```

to update the array:

```
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    users.doc().update({mobile_number:FieldValue.arrayUnion(['+524262727282'])
```

read more on firestorm usage [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

Using real-time database:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
final _userRef = database.child('users');
_userRef.set({'mobile_number': ['+1234567890','+0987654321']});
```

you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65510707/4571266) for real-time database

Comment: and what if i have two mobile numbers added already and now I want to add third mobile number ? @regnex

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do that is to add the value as a stringified JSON object

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: https://suragch.medium.com/parsing-simple-json-in-flutter-83ee1809a6ab